# Changing url depending on data attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many images on a webpage with class name **.champions-category**
Each of them has a data attribute called **data-window** coming dynamically from database. What I want to do is to check every element with class **.champions-category** and depending on the content of **data-window**'s content to change image's **src**.

```
<img src="" class="champions-category" data-window="teamwork">
<img src="" class="champions-category" data-window="focus">
<img src="" class="champions-category" data-window="results">
```

Suppose it's some kind of each and then if else statement but don't know where to start from.

Comment: start from an each and an if else, if that's what you think you need. Research those commands, find out how to select the elements you need, try something yourself. Interesting though - you mention that the data-window value comes from the DB, and according to that you must change the "src" property...is there some uncertainty about what it can be assigned as? e.g. a window value of "teamwork" always results in the same "src" value, or can it vary according to other factors? If it always results in the same thing, then can't you just inject that from the server as well?

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with you can try [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$("img.champions-category[data-window='teamwork']").attr("src", "/path")
```

You can replace *teamwork* with *whatever* later. You can play around with the business logic on how to decide the url.

Comment: I like this answer better

Comment: Thank you very much, very simple and effective solution. Gonna try all other solutions later, thanks everyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using using jQuery `Each` and then using a switch statement to change the image based on the `data attribute`.

Here's a working example:

```js
$('.champions-category').each(function(){

  var getDataAttribute = $(this).attr('data-window');

  switch (getDataAttribute) {
      case 'teamwork':
          $(this).attr('src','http://via.placeholder.com/20x200')
          break;
      case 'focus':
          $(this).attr('src','http://via.placeholder.com/40x200')
          break;
      case 'results':
          $(this).attr('src','http://via.placeholder.com/60x200')
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="" class="champions-category" data-window="teamwork">
<img src="" class="champions-category" data-window="focus">
<img src="" class="champions-category" data-window="results">
```

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery .each:

```
$('img.champions-category').each(function() {
   var self = $(this),
      type = self.data('window');

   if (type === 'teamwork') self.attr('src', 'teamwork-src-value-here.png');

  //etc
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will replace the src with the contents of the data-attribute:

```
$('.champions-category').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var windowData = $this.data('window');
  // Do data validation and manipulation here if needed.
  $this.attr('src', windowData);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("img.champions-category[data-window]").each(function(){
       var self = $(this);
       self.attr("src",self.data("window")+".png");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot has been said already, but let me add my 2 cents to this question.

```js
img_urls = {
  "teamwork": "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-management-set-4-1/256/5-128.png",
  "focus": "https://heyfocus.com/assets/img/icon/FocusActiveAppIcon128px.png",
  "results": "https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2016/09/05/825358_file_512x512.png",
  "question": "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/25/25400.png"
}
$("img.champions-category").each(function() {
  $(this).attr("src", img_urls[$(this).data("window")]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="" class="champions-category" data-window="teamwork">
<img src="" class="champions-category" data-window="focus">
<img src="" class="champions-category" data-window="results">
```

We can use `data-window` attribute data to assign the image sources as coded above. `img_urls` json can contain the image sources for all the possible `data-window` values.